# Jetpack Compose state handling with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In my Jetpack Compose projects I always use ViewModels and there I have StateFlow data class that consists of different states. For example isLoading, productsList, shouldShowDialog etc.

And my questions is, there are different state handlers such as derivedStateOf. If I manage state in my viewModel, do I need to use state handlers or it is reserved for values, that are declared in composable? If yes, then why would I even need stare handlers if state is being handled by viewModel?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you have the freedom to use various state holders within your Android ViewModel. Personally, I tend to lean towards using `Flows` for data streams and rely on `StateFlows` for state and `Channels` for managing events.

You can also use State obtained from either `mutableState` or `derivedStateOf`. These provide you with a snapshot state `State<T>`, and will be notified whenever the value changes.

Here is an example where I am using state variables from a ViewModel and updating them from the UI, at the same time we have a different state property which is dependent on the TextField and gets updated in real-time.

```
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeSamplesTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column {
                        TextField(value = viewModel.name, onValueChange = { viewModel.name = it })
                        Text(text = viewModel.age)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MainViewModel.kt
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var name by mutableStateOf("John Doe")
    val age by derivedStateOf {
        "$name is 25 years old!"
    }
}
```